# Set an external order ID when creating programmatically a WooCommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I've been using some well documented code to programatically create Woocommerce orders. Working great. Reference here: https://quadlayers.com/add-products-woocommerce/

However I'd be keen to know if it's possible to define the order_id (or is that the post_id?) whilst creating my WC orders via a script. I run this code on my shop, which currently imports orders into Woocommerce from a marketplace online where orders already have an Order number and I'd be keen to cut out the cross-referencing via this hack, and pass along the existing Order number to WC.

Here's a rough idea of what I have;

```
$insert_marketplace_order_id = 1234567890;

$order = wc_create_order();
$order->set_order_id($insert_marketplace_order_id);
$order->set_date_created($date_here);
$order-> etc. etc.
$order->save();
```

I've obviously searched around, unfortunately the existence of a plugin - *which seems to be all Google knows about it* - doesn't help.

I would have though '**set_order_id**' would do the trick, but perhaps there's an issue with where I'm placing it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WooCommerce, **the order Id is the post Id**, so you can't insert an external reference Id as you are trying to do. WooCommerce orders are a custom post type and order Id (the post Id) is generated from last post Id used in `wp_posts` database table…

Now you can set instead **an Order number** using [the filter hook `woocommerce_order_number`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/4.7.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L480), to set your own order reference number **as order number**, which is not the WooCommerce Order Id *(post Id)*.

So your code will be:

```php
$insert_marketplace_order_id = 1234567890;

$order = new WC_Order();
$order->set_date_created($date_here);

// $order-> etc. etc.

$order->update_meta_data('_order_number', $insert_marketplace_order_id); // <== Here
$order->save();
```

Then you will add the following hooked function to be able to get and display the correct order number:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'wc_set_order_number', 10, 2 );
function wc_set_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {

    // Get the order number (custom meta data)
    $order_number = $order->get_meta('_order_number'); 

    return empty($order_number) ? $order_id : $order_number;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

> Now when using the `WC_Order` method `get_order_number()` WooCommerce will get/display the correct order number.

**Note:** As you don't use any arguments with [`wc_create_order()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.0/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L76-L139) is better to use `$order = new WC_Order();` instead, which gives an empty `WC_Order` instance object without using `save()` method 2 times *(so much lighter)*.

**Related:** [Dynamic custom order numbers based on payment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545576/dynamic-custom-order-numbers-based-on-payment-method/63910184#63910184)

Comment: Loic, you most wonderful Aztec. You always come to the rescue. Not only a complete answer but very interesting you point out the lightweight $order = new WC_Order(); function. I will make the edit and let you know how it goes. Thank you so much. This looks great. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: If you look to [`wc_create_order()` function source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.0/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L76-L139), you will see that it uses `new WC_Order()`and the method `save()`. Thats why…