# WooCommerce (HPOS) not placing new order in checkout after adding my custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

In my WooCommerce plugin I'm using  `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook to handle custom checkout fields I added.

First I add action:
`add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', __NAMESPACE__ . '\my_update_order_meta');`

here below the function:

```
`function my_update_order_meta()
{
 $order = new \WC_Order();
 $billing_fields = ['billing_fiscalcode', 'billing_vatcode'];

 foreach ($billing_fields as $field) {
   if (!empty(sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]))) {
      $order->update_meta_data($field, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]));
   }
 }
}`
```

When I try to place an order in my shop I get a checkout error. Diving a little in the code I got that I'm not placing the order because its id is 0. Any idea about a solution?

I tried to use wc_create_order() as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897740/set-an-external-order-id-when-creating-programmatically-a-woocommerce-order), I'm still failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution. I used `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` as suggested by LoicTheAztec (thanks for help!), then I edited the function like this:

```
function add_custom_order_metadata( $order, $data ) {
    /** my new code starts here below **/
    
    $args = array(
           'orderby' => 'date',
           'order' => 'DESC',
           'return' => 'ids'
    );
   
    $order_ids = wc_get_orders($args);
    $new_order_id = empty($order_ids) ? 1 : max($order_ids) + 1;
    $order->set_id($new_order_id);  
  
    /** my new code ends here **/        

    foreach (['billing_fiscalcode', 'billing_vatcode'] as $field) {
        if ( isset($_POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field]) ) {
            $order->add_meta_data($field, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]), true);
        }
    }
}
```